# NSXMLParser does not parse last node (possible memory issue)

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser

I have the following .xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
    <employee>
        <id>0</id>
        <firstname>Jack</firstname>
        <lastname>Johnson</lastname>
        <jobtitle>CEO</jobtitle>
        <departmentid>0</departmentid>
        <parentid>0</parentid>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>1</id>
        <firstname>Mik</firstname>
        <lastname>Black</lastname>
        <jobtitle>Senior Manager</jobtitle>
        <departmentid>0</departmentid>
        <parentid>0</parentid>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>2</id>
        <firstname>Kim<firstname>
        <lastname>Friht</lastname>
        <jobtitle>Senior Manager</jobtitle>
        <departmentid>0</departmentid>
        <parentid>0</parentid>
    </employee>
...
```

The following header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Employee.h"


@interface IdParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
    NSMutableArray *employees;
    NSString *currentElement;

    Employee *employee;
    NSMutableString *tempId, *tempFirstName, *tempLastName, *tempDeptId, *tempJobTitle, *tempParentId;

}

-(NSMutableArray *)getSubordinates:(int)idNumber;

@end
```

And the following implementation:

```
#import "IdParser.h"
#import "Employee.h"

@implementation IdParser

- (void)start{

    NSString *file = @"/users/localadmin/Desktop/employeeData.xml";

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSData *dataBuffer = [filemgr contentsAtPath: file];

    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:dataBuffer];

    [xmlParser setDelegate:self]; 

    [xmlParser parse];

}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
     attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    [currentElement release];
    currentElement = [elementName copy];


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"employee"]){
        employee = [[Employee alloc]init];
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"id"]){
        tempId = [[NSMutableString alloc]init ];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"]){
        tempFirstName = [[NSMutableString alloc]init ];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastname"]){
        tempLastName = [[NSMutableString alloc]init ];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"jobtitle"]){
        tempJobTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc]init ];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"departmentid"]){
        tempDeptId = [[NSMutableString alloc]init ];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"parentid"]){
        tempParentId = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"id"]){
        [tempId appendString:string]; 
    }

    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"firstname"]){
        [tempFirstName appendString:string]; 
    }

    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"lastname"]){
        [tempLastName appendString:string]; 
    }

    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"jobtitle"]){
        [tempJobTitle appendString:string];

    }

    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"departmentid"]){
        [tempDeptId appendString:string]; 
    }

    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"parentid"]){
        [tempParentId appendString:string]; 
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"employee"]){

        [employee setIdNumber:[tempId intValue]];
        [tempId release];

        [employee setFirstName:tempFirstName];
        [tempFirstName release];

        [employee setLastName:tempLastName];
        [tempLastName release];

        [employee setJobTitle:tempJobTitle];
        [tempJobTitle release];

        [employee setDepartmentIdNumber:[tempDeptId intValue]];
        [tempDeptId release];

        [employee setParentIdNumber:[tempParentId intValue]];
        [tempParentId release]; //IF I REMOVE THIS LINE, THE PROGRAM DOES NOT CRASH

        [employees addObject:employee];
        [employee release];

    }

}

@end
```

I am experiencing a very strange problem with it. When I am to call the start method implemented in IdParser, it parses everything but when it gets to the last node of the XML (parentid), something strange happens.

The program quits and I receive the following error message:

malloc: *** error for object 0x4b33360: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc

Strangely, when I remove the `[tempParentId release];` line, the program runs fine. I have tried rearranging the elements in the XML and the same thing happens again: the program crashes at the last element. It does no make sense to me what is causing the problem as I am new to Objective-C and iOS so I am asking for help. I guess there is a memory problem somewhere because the program runs fine after I remove the line that I mentioned above.

Thanks for any help.

Petar

EDIT:

As I said I am new to Obj-C and I don't understand much about memory management and all the things connected with it so I am using this example to learn and expand my knowledge about it. That said, can you please try to explain what exactly is causing the error described before suggesting how to fix it.

EDIT2:

Sometimes when I run the code, instead of the error message which I described above, the program freezes and in the console I see just:

Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)

This may be a clue as to what the problem is because I am experiencing random behaviour.

EDIT3:

Employee class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Employee : NSObject {

    int idNumber;
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;
    int departmentIdNumber;
    NSString *jobTitle;
    int parentIdNumber;
}

-(id)initWithIdNumber:(int)idValue
             firstName:(NSString *)firstNameValue
             lastName:(NSString *)lastNameValue
   departmentIdNumber:(int)departmentIdNumberValue
             jobTitle:(NSString *)jobTitleValue
       parentIdNumber:(int)parentIdNumberValue;

@property(nonatomic) int idNumber;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstName;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastName;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *jobTitle;
@property(nonatomic) int departmentIdNumber;
@property(nonatomic) int parentIdNumber;

@end


#import "Employee.h"


@implementation Employee

@synthesize idNumber, firstName, lastName, departmentIdNumber, jobTitle, parentIdNumber;

-(id)initWithIdNumber:(int)idValue
            firstName:(NSString *)firstNameValue
             lastName:(NSString *)lastNameValue
   departmentIdNumber:(int)departmentIdNumberValue
             jobTitle:(NSString *)jobTitleValue
       parentIdNumber:(int)parentIdNumberValue{

    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        [self setIdNumber:idValue];
        [self setFirstName:firstNameValue];
        [self setLastName:lastNameValue];
        [self setDepartmentIdNumber:departmentIdNumberValue];
        [self setJobTitle:jobTitleValue];
        [self setParentIdNumber:parentIdNumberValue];
    }

    return self;

}

-(NSString *) description{
    NSString *desc = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"ID: %d, firstname: %@, lastname: %@, departmentID: %d, jobtitle: %@, parentID: %d", idNumber, firstName, lastName, departmentIdNumber, jobTitle, parentIdNumber];
    return desc;
}

@end
```

Comment: Is that all of your code? Are you sure you're not doing anything with `tempParentId` elsewhere?

Comment: It's all of the code. tempParentId is defined in the header file and accessed in the implementation file. I have copied them in full. Thanks

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but try setting `tempParentId` to `nil` immediately after releasing it. I can't see why that would be necessary in your code, but it's considered a good practice.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: setting tempParentId to nil actually solved the problem :) However, I do not understand why. Why should I not set the other variables to nil as well ? Can you please explain me what is going on. Thanks a lot

Comment: In general, whenever you're finished with a variable you should set it to `nil` to prevent anything from trying to use it. But if setting it to `nil` fixed the problem then here must be some serious bug somewhere in your code (I don't see any in what you've posted) and you should try to find it. The bug may or may not be a memory management issue... Objective-C is a low level language, and you're dealing with pointers. So the bug could be *almost anywhere* in your app. That's why I turn ARC on, so I never have headaches like these. You should set the others to `nil`.

Comment: Be aware we haven't fixed the actual problem yet, we only suppressed it (sending a message to a `nil` object is a null operation in Obj-C... which is why you were getting that error. But in general nothing should ever send messages to `nil`). The bug will probably re-appear somehow until you find it.

Comment: This is the whole of the program actually. These two files only. I am calling the start function from main.m , so if there is a bug it should be in the posted code.

Comment: Maybe the bug is in your `Employee` class. Or maybe the XML is invalid (you have `...` in the XML, so I assume there's more). And what about the `getSubordinates:` method? maybe the bug is in that. If it is a memory related issue, it could literally be anywhere.

Comment: The XML is not invalid, thats for sure. The getSubordinatesMethod is implemented in the implementation file, I just swapped the name with "start" to make it look simpler for the question. I am including the Employee implementation in the question as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sometimes when your app throws an exception, Xcode will pause the app and take you to the debug console without actually printing the exception out in the console. I don't know why this happens, but hitting "continue" several times in the debugger seems to eventually print out the exception. Looks like that may be happening to you in EDIT2. Random behaviour is often a memory/pointer issue. Again, try turning ARC on and see if it goes away.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you enable ARC, which will instruct the compiler to write all memory management code for you. As far as I can tell, it does a better job than most experienced Objective-C developers, and certainly better than new ones.

Everything you need to know about ARC is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

You can enable it for an existing project with `Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC…`. Which will modify the code in your project to be ARC compatible (so make sure you create a backup or commit to source control before doing this!).

Beware ARC code will not run on very old versions of iOS. Shouldn't be an issue though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that does not solve my problem. If I wanted to use ARC I would never have asked the question. I want to write my program without ARC and thus asking for help.

Comment: Just offering it because I know it almost certainly will solve your problem. And there aren't many reasons to turn ARC off except for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Manual memory management : ARC :: Washboard : Washing Machine

Comment: For what it's worth, there are definitely some memory leaks/bugs in your code if the XML contains any invalid structure. Turning on ARC would fix the leaks at least.

Comment: As a long-time ObjC developer who is nuts about people really learning ObjC and not just "hacking on it," even I say: use ARC. There is very little reason for new developers working on iOS 5+ or 10.7+ to learn manual memory management until they've been developing for a while and need to interact with Core Foundation. Memory management used to be a basic "you have to know it day 1" skill. Now it's much, much better to think in object graphs like ARC encourages. You'll write cleaner code that's more stable and runs faster. And by the way, it's easier to write.

Answer (score 2):

You are breaking the first rule of ObjC memory management: don't access your ivars directly. Use accessors everywhere but `dealloc` and `init`. This will take care of most memory management problems (and solves several other problems to boot). You have a lot of tricky memory management in the above code that would all go away if you used accessors.

@Abhi Beckert's comment about ARC is good, and if you can use ARC you should. IMO, it is the best addition to ObjC many years, and everyone should use it. But even with ARC, use accessors.

Comment: One more reason to access ivars directly is performance, which could be a valid point in an XML parser. But there's a lot of other optimisations his code needs before accessing them directly would have any benefit.

Comment: It can be, and I've done it for some very high performance pieces of code (with comments explaining why it was appropriate in that case), and it's occasionally necessary with interfacing with C and C++ code where you need to pass actual addresses by reference. But as you say, it's something you do for very special code, not a normal behavior.

Comment: @RobNapier: if I am to make the instance variables as global variables in the implementation file am I still going to break the rule of memory management ? Is my program supposed to work if I am to put the variables as global variables ? Thanks

Comment: Accessor methods for your instance variables do not need to be public. Most classes intended to be used by third parties will have some private accessor methods, though I usually don't bother for my code.

Comment: Why would you make these global? Do you mean public? As @AbhiBeckert notes, you don't have to make properties public. You can declare them in a private interface extension inside the .m file.

Comment: I just wanted to solve the problem that I described. As you suggested that I should define accessors I taught I could make the same effect by making them public. I am just trying to see what is the difference between declaring the variables public and creating accessors for them and store them in the .h file. Thanks